# Using Spring Data to Page

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I have a class that returns a `List<UserObject>` containing 184 items to my repository. This isn't hitting a database but the List contains what I expect.

```
 List<UserObject> objectList = UserObjectData.getObjectArray();
```

In my repository, I have a Pageable object that should return 2 items per page, starting at page 0. It has these attributes:

```
  System.out.println(pageable.getPageSize());  // returns '2'
  System.out.println(pageable.getOffset());  // returns '0'
  System.out.println(pageable.getPageNumber());  // returns '0'
```

Then I create a `Page<UserObject>` like this:

```
  Page<UserObject> theObjects = new PageImpl<UserObject>(objectList, pageable, objectList.size());
```

... and this is what comes back:

```
  System.out.println(theObjects.getSize());  // returns '2'
  System.out.println(theObjects.getNumber());  // returns '0'
  System.out.println(theObjects.getNumberOfElements());  // returns '184'
  System.out.println(theObjects.getTotalElements());  // returns '184'
  System.out.println(theObjects.getTotalPages());  // returns '92'
```

I pass `Page<UserObject>` back to a controller that returns it to a REST client but that response contains all 184 items, not 2 like I expect.

Does the above code look correct; especially the `new PageImpl<UserObject>`? If so, my problems might be in how I'm handling the `Page<UserObject>` 
in the controller and I'll focus on figuring out what I'm doing wrong there.

**EDIT: following is the code in full:**

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
  private UserObjectService service;
  NewUserRepository newUserRepository;

  @RequestMapping(value = "getObjects", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public Page<UserObject> getObjects(@RequestParam int page, @RequestParam int size) {
    Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(page,size);
    newUserRepository = new NewUserRepository();
    Page<UserObject> newPageResult = newUserRepository.findAll(pageable);
    return newPageResult;
}


public class NewUserRepository implements PagingAndSortingRepository<UserObject, Long> {
  public Page<UserObject> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
    List<UserObject> objectList = UserObjectData.getObjectArray(); // I can verify this contains 184 items
        Page<UserObject> theObjects = new PageImpl<UserObject>(objectList, pageable, objectList.size());
        return theObjects;
}
```

Comment: Posting some actual code would be useful rather than a bunch of print statements....

Answer (score 0):

Change page object creation to this:

```
Page<UserObject> theObjects = new PageImpl<UserObject>(objectList, pageable, (pageable.getOffset() + pageable.getPageSize()));
```